# DAG: are there situations where adjusting for mediators is reasonable?

Tags: matching, adjustment, dag

One thing about DAGs keeps bugging me - **are there situations where adjusting for mediators is reasonable?**

E.g. consider the experiment below, where a power-calculated sample of subjects participated in a hunger study and a bunch of them failed to complete the study protocol (secretly ate X grams of snacks before the end of the experiment). Their exclusion wouldn't be good since sample N would be insufficient for analysis. Adjusting would solve the problem, however, it would mean that matching variables involve mediators.

[image]

**Are there cases where mediator-adjustment is reasonable?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mediator adjustment is reasonable if you are interested in the direct effect of the treatment on the outcome that does not pass through the mediator. For example, in racial disparity studies, matching on variables caused by race (e.g., SES, education, location) allows one to isolate the effect of race that is not explained by those features and must instead be explained by an additional pressure applied differentially by race. Although this involves matching on mediators, it allows one to more clearly isolate the unique effect of race that is not explainable by known pathways. This is a common method used in disparity studies.

Your case actually seems like it might be ripe for principal stratification, which is a method used to estimate treatment effects when not everyone obeys the treatment condition they were assigned to. From the principal stratification perspective, there are four groups of units: compliers (who do as they are asked), noncompliers (who do the opposite of what they are asked), never-takers (who never take the treatment regardless of their assignment), and always-takers (who always take the treatment regardless of their assignment). In your example, you could think of food deprivation as the treatment and consider that some units did not comply because they ate secretly against the will of the experimenter. There are statistical techniques to determine the effect of the treatment among compliers (often called the complier average treatment effect), which is typically the target of inference. It may be a bit more complicated given that you have a continuous treatment, but it's a place to start.